# How to multiply DATETIME in MySQL by INT?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to multiply a DATETIME in MySQL by an INT.

I have the following table structure:

Table name -> purchases

```
purchase_id    date_purchased          user_id     duration_in_months /*(INT)*/
1              yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss     4           1
2.             yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss     12          6
```

I'd like to select the date the purchase expires along with the user_id, what I've come up with so far is this query:

```
SELECT `date_purchased` + (INTERVAL 1 MONTH * `duration_in_months`), `user_id`
FROM `purchases`
```

But it's not working, what am I doing incorrectly? I'm not quite sure how to add time intervals in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` function. [Documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

`SELECT DATE_ADD(date_purchased , INTERVAL duration_in_months MONTH ),userid FROM purchases`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `date_purchased` + INTERVAL `duration` MONTH, `user_id`
FROM `purchases`
```

Comment: If you move the first `(` to before `\`date_purchased\``, it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`date_purchased` ,INTERVAL `duration_in_months` MONTH), `user_id` 
FROM `purchases`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (date_purchased + (INTERVAL duration MONTH) as new_time,
    user_id
FROM purchases
```